# How can I hide the launcher when I press Super + S?

Tags: unity, launcher, workspaces

Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on Ubuntu with workspaces enabled activates a workspace switcher/expo thing (I'm not sure what it's called, exactly, so I'm not sure what to search for). One thing that's bothering me about it (for purely aesthetic reasons) is that the launcher always appears on the left.

I have no idea where I should go to configure the settings of whatever this is, because I'm not even sure what it's called. Is there a good way to do this in Ubuntu 14.04? I'm willing to go so far as removing or hiding the launcher completely (though it seems that that's not so easy), or installing another program to accomplish this.

Comment: Unfortunately, Unity on a whole is very limited in this way so without running a process constantly to hide it that you make yourself it will be very hard. Not an answer (and if you like Unity then you be yourself my friend!) but if it bothers you such an incredible amount, a drastic solution is changing launchers...or editing and recompiling Unity (even more drastic probably). Good luck sir!

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm answering my own question, but if anyone else is wondering how to do this, I discovered with a little tinkering that you can do this with the Compiz configuration settings manager.

In ccsm, under 'Expo' (what this thing is apparently called), there is an option in the 'Appearance' tab to 'Hide Panels/Docks'. Checking this and setting the X offset to 0 accomplishes what I wanted.

(Unfortunately, I've found that ccsm appears to be a little finicky, and it took a few restarts before this worked. I can only hope it sticks.)